# How to set a php variable inside a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, one-time-password

I want to create an OTP sender and checker.
The code is like this:

```html
<?php
 $Mail = "someone@gmail.com";
  $OTP = mt_rand();
  $subject = "OTP from HelloBuddy.co.in";
  $txt = "You have recieved OTP from HelloBuddy.co.in. The OTP is $OTP. Please enter the OTP in the website. Please note that the OTP will expire in 100 seconds.";
    if (mail($Mail,$subject,$txt)){
   echo "<p>OTP has been successfully sent<br>The OTP will expire in <span id='xpire'>100</span> seconds.<br>Please enter the OTP here:<input type='number' name ='OTP'></p>";
   echo "<script>
     var a = 99;
     var x = setInterval(cdown, 1000);
     function cdown(){
      if (a>=0) {
       document.getElementById('xpire').innerHTML = a;
       a=a-1;
      } else {
       clearInterval(x);
       clearOTP()
      }
     function clearOTP{
     $OTP = '';
          }
          </script>";
    }else{
   die(ERROR);
}
?>
```

I am using xampp server and have correctly configured the required files.
I want to clear the OTP after 100 seconds, but cant, perhaps because it is inside a javscript function.
If possible, give an AJAX.

Comment: You can use php varaibles inside javascirpt by defining it as followed:    "<?php yourPhPCode ?>" .

Comment: But my javscript code is also inside a <?php ?>. Can there be <php ?> inside another <php ?>   ???

Comment: @HyperMaths.com The best way is to store OTP in session.

Comment: I would like to point out that mixing html/js/php/css together is a bad practice making the code difficult to read, modify and creates room for difficult to spot defects. Please look into a separation of concerns, MVC frameworks, and templating.

Comment: Thanh You. I have formatted it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set an php variable with javascript.

PHP will get executed server side and javascript executes on the client side. So all the PHP code is already executed before the javascript gets called.

The $OTP variable is already not saved. Because the code gets executes on the server side and will be garbage collected. If you want to save and delete the OTP you should use a database of some sort.

Comment: Is there any ajax alternative

Comment: I know that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use php tags before script then concat the php variables

try this,

```
<?php
$Mail = "someone@gmail.com";
    $OTP = mt_rand();
    $subject = "OTP from HelloBuddy.co.in";
    $txt = "You have recieved OTP from HelloBuddy.co.in. The OTP is $OTP. Please enter the OTP in the website. Please note that the OTP will expire in 100 seconds.";
if (mail($Mail,$subject,$txt)){
        echo "<p style='color:green; font-size:30px; text-align:center; text-decoration: underline;'>OTP has been successfully sent<br>The OTP will expire in <span id='xpire'>100</span> seconds.<br>Please enter the OTP here:<form method ='POST' action = ''  style='text-align:center'><input style='color:green; font-size:30px; text-align:center;text-decoration: underline;'type='number' name ='OTP'><input style='color:white; background-color:#4CAF50;border:2px #4caf50 solid; font-size:30px; cursor:pointer;' type='submit' value='Check'></form></p>";
        ?><script>
                var a = 99;
                var x = setInterval(cdown, 1000);
                function cdown(){
                    if (a>=0) {
                        document.getElementById('xpire').innerHTML = a;
                        a=a-1;
                    } else {
                        clearInterval(x);
                        clearOTP()
                    }
                function clearOTP{<?=$OTP ='';?>}
      </script>

<?
    }
?>
```

Comment: Cant you elaborate

Comment: What if the mail() has a problem? Means like else{die(ERROR)}. The function will be performed even then?

Comment: what do you mean by mail() has a problem? your mail function has an error?

Comment: IF it has a problem

Comment: your script inside your  if condition will not be performed  if your mail() has a problem

Comment: take note that <? tags are now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Php variables can be only used in JS, can't be manipulated (initialization/update).
The above task can be used via ajax, keep the value of otp in js and to reset, use ajax to perform some other operations like OPT verfication.